# IndexOutOfBoundsException issue

Tags: arraylist

So, I'm writing a code to find the longest increasing subsequence in a input numbers.

```
    int curr_len = 0, max_len = 0, start = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= listN.size(); i++){
        if (listN.get(i-1) < listN.get(i)){
            curr_len++;
            if (curr_len >= max_len){
                max_len = curr_len;
                start = i - max_len + 1;
            }
        } else {
            curr_len = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max_len; i++)
        listAsc.add(start+i);
```

The problem is that I got IndexOutOfBoundsException in that fragment of code

```
    if (listN.get(i-1) < listN.get(i))
```

Anyone can help how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for (int i = 1; i < listN.size(); i++){
```

as the index starts at 0. Using an index < 0 or >= listN.size() causes a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in get(i).

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29

Comment: This is true, but the way OP has it won't cause an IOOB, it'll just iterate once less than it should.  1 - list.N.size() -1 should still be a valid range, if not incorrect.